# Finding the Generate and kill set using GCC

Tags: c, optimization, gcc, compiler-construction

I want to do a project for compiler optimization in which I need the Generate and kill set for each basic block. So I want to know is there any way to extract this information using GCC for a c program.

Comment: For experimentation with compilers you should probably look into [clang](http://clang.llvm.org/) and [LLVM](http://llvm.org/). They are made for this kind of job, while GCC is not.

Answer (score 0):

You probably need to implement a custom CGC pass for that. You can start with the following

1. http://gcc.gnu.org/wiki/WritingANewPass - adding a new pass to GCC infrastructure.
2. http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gccint/ - GCC internals documentation (this document is quite long and might be a bit confusing). PDF link: http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gccint.pdf

For the sake of a simple data flow analysis you can take a look into SSA section:
http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gccint/SSA.html#SSA (search for use-def chains)